# creating an infinitely long sine tone in Python

Tags: python, audio, numpy, trigonometry, pyaudio

I'm trying to create an infinitely long pure sine tone in Python (so I can later add realtime on/off events) and while I can get a tone playing, it is choppy and clipped.  My assumption is that it's either from the next chunk not starting in the same place in the wave's cycle as the last chunk ended, or that there is a delay in calculating the next chunk, and I have no idea which it is.

Are either of those things occurring, or have I made some other error?  Moreover, is there a better approach to take without sacrificing the ability to alter the incoming data in real time?

```
import time
import numpy
import pyaudio
import math

CHUNK = 4096
RATE = 44100

def sine(current_time, frequency=440):
    length = CHUNK
    factor = float(frequency) * (math.pi * 2) / RATE
    this_chunk = numpy.arange(length) + current_time
    return numpy.sin(this_chunk * factor)

def get_chunk():
    data = sine(time.time())
    return data * 0.1

def callback(in_data, frame_count, time_info, status):
    chunk = get_chunk() * 0.25
    data = chunk.astype(numpy.float32).tostring()
    return (data, pyaudio.paContinue)

p = pyaudio.PyAudio()
stream = p.open(format = pyaudio.paFloat32,
                channels = 2,
                rate = RATE,
                output = True,
                stream_callback = callback)

stream.start_stream()

while stream.is_active():
    time.sleep(0.1)

stream.stop_stream()
stream.close()
```

Answer (score -2):

Looks like you need some optimization see,

https://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonSpeed/PerformanceTips

try:

```
import time
import numpy
import pyaudio
import math

CHUNK = 4096
RATE = 44100

MP = math.pi
NA = numpy.arange
NS = numpy.sin
TT = time.time
NF32 = numpy.float32
p = pyaudio.PyAudio()
PO = p.open
PC = pyaudio.paContinue
PF = pyaudio.paFloat32
TS = time.sleep

def sine(current_time, frequency=440):
    length = CHUNK
    factor = float(frequency) * (MP * 2) / RATE
    this_chunk = NA(length) + current_time
    return NS(this_chunk * factor)*  0.025



def callback(in_data, frame_count, time_info, status):
    chunk = sine(TT())
    data = chunk.astype(NF32).tostring()
    return (data, PC)


stream = PO(format = PF,
                channels = 2,
                rate = RATE,
                output = True,
                stream_callback = callback)

stream.start_stream()

while stream.is_active():
    TS(0.1)

stream.stop_stream()
stream.close()
```

Comment: I ran both his code sample and yours on a Win 7, Intel i7 CPU laptop. Still a grievous amount of clipping.
You may want to consider how you're packing sine values into the chunk. If the sine function resets its state between chunks, you might get a nasty discontinuity between the end of one chunk and the start of the next.

Comment: I actually ended up solving it!  The problem was that the sine wave wasn't picking up from where it left off, so to rectify this, I appended the last value of every chunk (from the numpy.arange(length) bit) to the beginning of the next chunk, and it worked perfectly.  But thanks for the suggestions!

Comment: @user3006166: You should post that as a separate answer.  Instead of `arange`, you want `linspace(endpoint=False)`?